# Using Karma + Jasmine, what is the best way to run only one test at a time?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Is the best way to do that, simply to use the .only flag?

However, if I used `describe.only(`, I get

```
 Uncaught TypeError: describe.only is not a function
```

**So how can I run/debug only one test at a time?**

Here is my karma.conf.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      // './public/pages/admin/specs/abc.js'
      './public/dist/app-production.js',
      // './public/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {},

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['spec', 'junit', /*progress*/],

    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'karma-results',
      outputFile: 'karma-results.xml'
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config['LOG_WARN'],

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: [/*Chrome*/ 'PhantomJS'],

    //  process.env.USER === dftjenkins

    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-junit-reporter',
      'karma-spec-reporter'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: 5
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have for the moment works quite well, all I do is change one line of our karma.conf.js file, like so:

before:

```
 files: [
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      './public/dist/app-production.js',
      './public/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
```

after:

```
  files: [
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      './public/dist/app-production.js',
      process.env.KARMA_TEST_PATH || './public/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
```

now your just run karma like so:

```
KARMA_TEST_PATH=public/pages/x/specs/foo.spec.js karma start
```

and it will run that single test instead of all your specs.